# Why is my JSON looking like this and what can I do about it?

Tags: views, 8

On Drupal 8, I enabled the serialization and restful web services and I created a restful view in order to create a map. The format is WKT. However, the output looks like the below.

[image: views restful output]

Can/should I do something about it? Can this be parsed as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the presence of `\u003Ca` and similar...

It's like that because [`Json::encode`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Serialization%21Json.php/function/Json%3A%3Aencode/8.6.x) uses the [`JSON_HEX_TAG`/`JSON_HEX_QUOT`/etc](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-hex-tag) flags. It's done to ensure that all strings in the document are [RFC4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) compliant.

You shouldn't need to worry about this, any compliant parser will happily translate the hex back to the original characters.